# Why is Task.Wait() causing application to freeze

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

When I call BuildCustomer.StartTask, I then call a method WriteToDatabase. Inside WriteToDatabase, I want to send a status back to the MainForm to write the status to the GUI. When the code reaches that point, my application freezes up and gives no error. I did find out that if I remove task.Wait(), it stops freezing and works. But I think I want the wait in because my BuildCustomer takes a bit of time and writes a lot of updates (including more updates from Common class) to the GUI. Can someone tell me what is wrong or what I should be doing differently? This is a .Net 4 project so I cannot use async, which I've seen other answers for.

```
public partial class MainForm : Window
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        Common.SendMessage += UpdateStatus;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BuildCustomer.StartTask();
    }

    private void UpdateStatus(string message)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            StatusTextBox.Text = message;
        }));
    }
}

public class BuildCustomer
{
    public static void StartTask()
    {
        var action = new Action<object>(BuildCustomer);

        var task = new Task(() => action(buildDetails));

        task.Start();

        task.Wait();
    }

    private void BuildCustomerDetails(object buildDetails)
    {
        Common.WriteToDatabase();
    }
}

public class Common
{
    public delegate void MessageLogDelegate(string message);

    public static event MessageLogDelegate SendMessage;

    public static void WriteToDatabase()
    {
        SendMessage("Some status message to write back to the GUI");
    }
}
```

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto `StartNew` in this case, as it's 4.0, not 4.5, but other than that, yes.

Comment: I think Task.Run() is probably not available for you, but Task.StartNew() should be, and I'd be using that.  Also you have some bugs in here that I think the compiler should be catching.

Comment: It freezes because `.Wait()` is a blocking call and will not allow the UI thread to do anything else until the task is completed. And if you are willing to, you can use async/await in .Net 4: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2012/10/22/using-asyncawait-without-net-framework-4-5/

Comment: Never block the UI thread, all the heavy weight operations should go in a secondary thread, then if you want to access to the UI thread you can use the current dispatcher of your application.

Comment: I'd suggest reading these articles
[Task.Run Etiquette Examples: Don't Use Task.Run for the Wrong Thing](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html)
[Task.Run Etiquette Examples: Don't Use Task.Run in the Implementation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html)

remove the Task from your class and use Task.StartNew in your button click event handler

Comment: I'd suggest reading [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) by Stephen Cleary.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and reading assignments :). I will definitely read those.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a deadlock. The `StartTask` waits on `task.Wait()` to complete but this occurs (is called on) on the calling thread which is the main UI thread.

The `Task` being waited eventually reaches `UpdateStatus` which calls an Invoke on the UI thread as well but this thread is currently waiting on `task.Wait()` (*so it is blocking which results in the UI thread not being available indefinitely*).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add async keyword to method signature and use this:

```
await task;
```

It cause to does not sleep main thread(UI thread).

Comment: async is not available in 4.0 without an add-on which I cannot do.

Answer (score -1):

For those who can't use the async/await keywords: Use Task.ContinueWith() to continue code execution after the task has been completed.